# Using Scandit BarcodeScanner in 2 fragment of an application

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I develop an application for scanning barcode. My application is an Android TabView application with 2 tabs. And I want to add barcode scanner in both of them.

My code is following:

**Fragment1:**

```
public class WebServiceFragment extends Fragment {

    RelativeLayout scanServiceView;
    ScanditSDKAutoAdjustingBarcodePicker barcodePicker;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webservice_layout, container, false);

        scanServiceView = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.scanserviceview);
        barcodePicker = new ScanditSDKAutoAdjustingBarcodePicker(getActivity(), "<My Scandit SDK Key 1>", ScanditSDKAutoAdjustingBarcodePicker.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
        barcodePicker.startScanning();

        scanServiceView.addView(barcodePicker);

        return v;
    }
}
```

**Fragment2:**

```
public class CMCSMOFragment extends Fragment {

    RelativeLayout scanSMOView;
    ScanditSDKAutoAdjustingBarcodePicker barcodePicker;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cmcsmo_layout, container, false);

        scanSMOView = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.scansmoview);
        barcodePicker = new ScanditSDKAutoAdjustingBarcodePicker(getActivity(), "<My Scandit SDK Key 2>", ScanditSDKAutoAdjustingBarcodePicker.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
        barcodePicker.startScanning();

        scanSMOView.addView(barcodePicker);

        return v;
    }
}
```

But when I build, only `Fragment2` display camera view for scanning. `Fragment1` display black screen. If I remove `Fragment2` code which call `Scandit SDK`, `Fragment1` would work normally.
How should I do with this situation? Image below is the issue screen:

1. Fragment1:

[image]

2. Fragment2:

[image]

Comment: Do you ever tell it to stop scanning?

Comment: @Cheesebaron: You mean when I move between fragments, I should stop one, bro? If this is your mind, I have not done it. I will try this. Thanks for your advice ^^

Comment: You saved my days, bro ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments you will need to stop the scanning when navigating away from the Fragment.

This is due to the Fragment is not having its view destroyed when simply navigating away. So your reference to the barcodePicker does not get collected as long as you are holding on to that reference.

The camera does not allow multiple sources to connect to it, hence you will have to disconnect from it before attempting to use it somewhere else.